# How to get rid of this shed?

Tags: shed, demolition

I have a shed in my garden, and I'd like to remove it to plant trees instead. But I am not exactly sure how I can go about it, and would appreciate advice. I've included 2 pictures of the shed below.

The shed is basically made of wood or some sort of plywood, nailed together. I could not see how the roof is attached. Is there a better way than simply brute force to dismantle the walls and roof?

There are also some electric cables in the shed. I am not sure they are connected to anything, but how to best handle them?

Also, the floor is made of pure concrete, and a fair amount of it by the looks of things. How can I remove that, and how do I dispose of the material?

[image: Garden Shed: View from outside]

[image: Garden Shed: View from the inside]

Comment: what tools do you have?

Comment: I cannot tell a lie, I cut it up with my Sawzall !   lmao

Comment: This shed is in such a good condition. I think you should consider dissembling it and sell the parts. Is the base cemented into the ground? If you find getting rid of the concrete troublesome, you could consider making it into an elevated flower bed that sits on the  concrete slab.

Answer (score 4):

I would advertise "Free Shed" on Craigslist. I had a tree house I constructed for my grand kids, and when they outgrew it that's what I did. Some folks came out one Saturday, disassembled it, and took it away. They did the whole job. I just got to watch.

Answer (score 3):

1. You have electrical in your shed.  Before doing anything that branch needs to be terminated correctly.
2. I don't think there is a pure art to the small demo.  I personally would slice the front wall beams halfway up with whatever saw I thought would be the quickest and then sledge hammer from the corners.  Roof should fall/slide down.  Then I would just start cutting and busting stuff up.
3. The concrete can be handled with a large sledge hammer or jack hammer.  I don't own a jack hammer and I like using a sledge hammer so I would personally go that route for an area this small.  You just need to break up the chunks in small enough pieces that they can be disposed of.
4. Most local trash companies will set out a large "bag" or container for projects like this on your driveway.  Cost is usually $100-200.  They have weight limits but you should be OK.
5. I would really be worried about planting a tree there.  Your brick work looks really nice.  A growing tree could really tear up all of that.  Also on the edges of the brick that hit the concrete you will need to put in a larger stone or divider to keep the outer bricks from moving.

Not telling you to not destroy your shed but know that it could be a lot more work then just tearing it down.  Also you would need to talk to an arborist about what kind of tree won't have roots that detroy your walkways.  The concrete inside looks well done.  I would think of alternative - make a gazebo with some large planters or something.  You could stain/etch the concrete to fit in more with your yard too.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of tree roots. Had a sycamore root penetrate a footing defect and crack a foundation wall top to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

First, sort out the electrical and be triply certain it's disconnected but good.

Then, place an ad for "free shed, you remove"

Then place an ad for "free fill - unwanted Concrete slab, you break it up and take it away."

Only if those fail do you need to worry about removing it yourself.

Sucks to be Blake + Steve - not even two years use (it doesn't look 102, for sure.)

Comment: I think that says '92.  Not in bad shape for twenty one. I do feel for Blake + Steve, but then again, maybe they're dead.

Comment: In what area do people come over and break up a concrete slab for free AND haul the concrete out for fill?  Will they bring over a few tree choices too?

Comment: @DMoore - You try it. Some people go a little crazy at the thought of "free" stuff, so you exploit them if available. If not, you do the breaking up and try it again as free fill, already broken up; only if that also fails do you have to deal with disposing of it. Not guaranteed to work, but saves a lot of your time and money if it does, so it's worth a try. The shed will almost certainly go if listed correctly, and get re-used to boot.

Comment: I am a huge craigslister - both buying and selling - I can't imagine that anyone would break up concrete and haul it for free.  The shed is a 50/50 thing (because the person who answers it probably doesn't understand how to take it down or put it up or have the vehicle to haul it).  Please share with us an ad that gets people to your house to break up concrete.